# "E315: ml_get: invalid lnum: 87" error in vim

Tags: vim

When I try to change the tab with `gt` this error occurred :

```
"E315: ml_get: invalid lnum: 87"
```

You can see it in following picture:
[image]

If further information need, comment it.

Comment: Does this happen when you run without plugins and your vimrc. `vim -u NONE`

Comment: can you explain your comment?

Comment: @FDinoff I think for bugs in Vim it doesn't matter whether you start it with `-u NONE` or not. `-u NONE` might hide the bug, but eventually it needs to be fixed anyway.

Comment: @glts while it might hide the bug. if it didn't it probably meant his installation got corrupted.

Comment: `-u NONE` runs vim without sourcing your vimrc or plugins. The point of the comment was to eventually narrow down what could be causing it. If you could find out what the problem is (in a minimal configuration) it would be best to post it as a bug report on the mailing list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An unfamiliar error in Vim! What do you do?

Here's what:

1. Look it up.

   ```
   :h E315
   ```
2. Read what it says.

   > This is an internal Vim error.  Please try to find out how it can be reproduced, and submit a bug report |bugreport.vim|.
3. Understand what it says.

   It is a bug in Vim.
4. Act.

   Investigate the error conditions and file a bug on the [vim_dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_dev) mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

It always appear where I opened nerdtree plugin.

My solution is add:

```
" in .vimrc
let g:NERDTreeWinPos = "right"
```

It works for me. Good Luck.